# sys.stdin in for loop is not grabbing user input

Tags: python

I have this code (`test.py`) below:

```
import sys    
for str in sys.stdin.readline():
    print ('Got here')
    print(str)
```

For some reason when I run the program `python test.py` and then I type in `abc` into my terminal I get this output:

```
>>abc
THIS IS THE OUTPUT:
Got here
a
Got here
b
Got here
c
Got here
```

It prints out `Got here` five times and it also prints out each character `a`, `b`, `c` individually rather than one string like `abc`. I am doing `sys.stdin.readline()` to get the entire line but that doesn't seem to work either. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

I am new to python and couldn't find this anywhere else on stackoverflow so sorry if this is a obvious question.

Comment: You're reading the line, and then you're iterating over the returned string. Where is the problem?

Comment: why not use `input()` (or `raw_input()` in python2)? and `str` is not a good variable name!

Comment: @hiroprotagonist cannot use `input()` the professor provided a sample code using the for loop method in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through each character in the string that you got inputted.

```
import sys    
s = sys.stdin.readline()
print ('Got here')
print(s)

# Now I can use string `s` for whatever I want
print(s + "!")
```

In your original code you got a string from `stdin` and then you looped through ever character in that input string and printed it out (along with "Got here").

EDIT:

```
import sys
while True:
    s = sys.stdin.readline()

    # Now I can do whatever I want with string `s`
    print(s + "!")
```

Comment: Oh ok. I see now. But how would I get the entire string `abc` using a for loop? Like if I do `for line in sys.stdin:` like Ned suggessted, after I type abc the terminal is just stuck there.

Comment: Are you saying you want to get multiple lines of input?

Comment: No like when I type in `abcd` into the terminal after running `python test.py`, I want to get access to the entire string `abc` and use that in some computation inside of the for loop. The for loop is there so that after doing the computation it will keep asking for the user input I think.

Comment: I tried to edit my original answer, if I'm understanding you correctly.

Answer (score 2):

readline() reads a single line. Then you iterate over it. Iterating a string gives you the characters, so you are running your loop once for each character in the first line of input.

Use .readlines(), or better, just iterate over the file:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
```

But the best way to get interactive input from stdin is to use `input()` (or `raw_input()` in Python 2).

Comment: When I change the for loop to that, nothing happens on the screen. Like after I type `abc` the terminal is just stuck there.

Comment: That's because of buffering.  Reading sys.stdin directly isn't a good way to get input.  Use input() instead. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change it to `raw_input()` since the professor is using that for loop method.